# How do I properly encode &#322; and the like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, ruby-on-rails-4, character-encoding

I have legacy database imported into SQLite, with lots of fields containing URL-encoded strings. The legacy database was set up with latin1 encoding, and it has a lot of Polish characters encoded like this

> "b%26%23322%3Bad+zapisu+%2D+powinno+by%26%23263%3B+brak"

which after CGI::unescape gives

> "b&#322;ad zapisu - powinno by&#263; brak"

I tried enforcing ISO-8859-1 and cp1250 on strings to encode them into UTF-8, but had no success: I still end up with escaped Polish characters. I’ve been researching on this for two days now and still can’t find a solution. Would you please help me on this one?

Comment: Please check my edit, @adass, and let me know whether you're happy with it. I changed the encoding of some of your output. I think I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding because it's HTML encoding. You need to do this

```
CGI::unescapeHTML(CGI::unescape("b%26%23322%3Bad+zapisu+%2D+powinno+by%26%23263%3B+brak"))
```